# PHP: Почему в цикле while пустой массив не добавляется 2020 как первый элемент?

Tags: php, массивы, строки, while, int

на основе массива из csv пытаюсь собрать в цикле while массив строк $temp_array. Назначаю вместо первого элемента цифру 2020, но в получившийся массив, судя по print_r() она не попадает. Почему? ума не приложу.. Ниже то, что дает print_r, а еще ниже сам код:

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

```
if (($handle = fopen( 'VED2017.csv', 'r' )) !== false) {

// Получаю из csv ассоциированный массив PHP, готовый к загрузке в базу данных.
    fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {

$temp_array[] = "" . 2020 . ", '" . empty(trim($data[6])) ? 0 : 1 . "', '" . empty(trim($data[7])) ? 0 : 1 . "', '" . empty(trim($data[8])) ? 0 : 1 . "', '" . empty(trim($data[9])) ? 0 : 1 . "','$data[6]', '$data[7]', '$data[8]', '$data[9]', '$data[0]', '$data[5]', '" . 0 . "', '$data[1]')";
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary второй блок замечаний.

Comment: И пора уже почитать про sql-инъекции и перейти к подготовленным выражениям, а не вот это вот конструировать.